# Windows 10 title bars based on background color of window

Tags: windows-10, colors, window, title-bar

In windows 10 I know you can set **all** title bars to be a colour of your choosing.

Is it possible to have windows automatically set the colour of the title bar, based on the background colour of the window?

For example I have a dark todolist app:

[image: Todolist screenshot]

I'd like this app to have a dark grey title bar (the same as the header of the app itself)

Notepad++ however has a white background:

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]

So I'd like this app to keep its white title bar.

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 V1903 and up there is a setting to do this. I set my Title bar colours on my machines.  Start, Settings, Personalization, Colours and scroll down for "Show Accent Colours on Start, Titles.

[image]

Comment: That sets the title bar for all windows to the same colour. I am looking for different title bar colours for different windows.

Comment: There is no native Windows tool to do that and I am not aware of any robust third party tool that will do this and survive Windows Feature Updates (V2004 out very soon)